# Alarm not called on Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So I am trying to implement the repeating feature from this site - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/Exampleofschedulingoneshotandrepeatingalarms.htm - into my Android app but it's not calling the class for some reason here is the code excerpts.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

// Schedule repeating alarm

          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
          PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
              intent, 0);

          // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
          long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
          firstTime += 15 * 1000;

          // Schedule the alarm!
          AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
          am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,
              15 * 1000, sender);

          // Tell the user about what we did.
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

}

//Schedule alarm for data upload
class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "ALARMED!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
      }
}
```

If it helps the full code is here: https://gist.github.com/4410665

Comment: Is the receiver declared in the manifest?

Comment: That must be it then, cause this is basically the same code that's in the google example. I'm guessing this <receiver
    android:name=".receiver.RepeatingAlarm"></receiver> will fix it?

Comment: If that's the location of your receiver yes (so if you have an actual subpackage called receiver that has your RepeatingAlarm class in it).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and implement that and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Sweet that worked, I also create it as a separate class in its own file. Had to fix some other error cause it said the class was already defined but it looks like it is working correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to take:

```
//Schedule alarm for data upload
class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "ALARMED!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
      }
}
```

And save it as RepeatingAlarm.java basically it's own class. Then go into the mainfest file and add something of this effect

```
<receiver android:name="RepeatingAlarm"></receiver>
```